# nasm variable declaration joins other variable

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
SECTION .data       ; data section
msg:    db "Hello World",10 ; the string to print, 10=cr
test:   db "test",10
len:    equ $-msg       ; "$" means "here"
                ; len is a value, not an address

    SECTION .text       ; code section
        global main     ; make label available to linker 
main:               ; standard  gcc  entry point

    mov edx,len     ; arg3, length of string to print
    mov ecx,msg     ; arg2, pointer to string
    mov ebx,1       ; arg1, where to write, screen
    mov eax,4       ; write sysout command to int 80 hex
    int 0x80        ; interrupt 80 hex, call kernel

    mov ebx,0       ; exit code, 0=normal
    mov eax,1       ; exit command to kernel
    int 0x80        ; interrupt 80 hex, call kernel
```

Beginner question but why do this code  print "Hello word test " it was only expected to print msg so hello world"?

I build this way

```
nasm -f elf -g test.asm
gcc -m32 -g -o file test.o
```

Comment: It prints `len` bytes starting at `msg`. The value of `len` includes the length of both strings, so it prints both strings.

Comment: OK thanks I should write this way then. msg:    db "Hello World",10 ; the string to print, 10=cr
len:    equ $-msg